# why i can't use parantheses or colons or many other charachters in jinja?

Tags: django, jinja2

I need to use characters like `"()", "[]", ":"` or many other characters but when I write a code like this:

```
{% for cat, posts in cat_divided.items %}
  <div class="tab-pane animated fadeInRight" id="tab_{{ cat.replace(" ", "") }}">
```

I get the error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at / Could not parse the remainder: '(" ", "")'
  from 'cat.replace(" ", "")'
```

can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using a template tag. Just create a templatetags folder under your app directory. And create a new file in there e.g called templatefilters.py. Then inside your templatefilters file write the code below;

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def replace(word):
    return word.replace(" ", "")
```

And now you can use this method in any of your template file. Usage is like in below;

```
id="tab_{{ cat|replace}}"
```

Also dont forget to import template filters at the top of your html template

```
{% load templatefilters %}
```